# В чём смысл создания массива на 0 элементов

Tags: java

```
int[] indexOfTask = new int[0];
```

С какой целью такая возможность поддерживается компилятором?

Comment: а почему такая возможность не должна поддерживаться компилятором?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Есть такая замечательная книга "[Effective Java](http://www.informit.com/store/effective-java-9780134685991)" Джошуа Блоха, содержащая обширный список рекомендаций по проектированию и разработке эффективных, надёжных и легкосопровождаемых программ. Одна из рекомендаций звучит как "Возвращайте массивы и коллекции нулевой длины, а не null". Например, в классе `java.io.File` есть метод [listFiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()), который возвращает массив файлов каталога. Представьте, как неудобно было бы, если бы он не смог вернуть массив нулевой длины для пустых каталогов! Пришлось бы вместо лаконичного

```
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    ...
}
```

делать

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
    for (File file : files) {
        ...
    }
}
```